# Rubberband baseline correction

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectral-analysis

I am trying to code the method called "Rubber-band baseline correction" for baseline correction of vibrationnal spectra.
Could somebody please, explain me how does this method works? or provide any document which explains about this method?
Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a reference / link to this method?

Comment: Actually, I am working on the Convex Rubber band correction (http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US7359815). But, at the final step of this algorithm, they said that we need to perform a classic Rubberband correction method. I trying to figure that out, but I still don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EDIT:20190107 Added a 2018 refrence] As I cannot trace a genuine reference to the said  "Rubber-band baseline correction". The mention appears in different sources with more or less details, like in:

- [Study on baseline correction methods for the Fourier transform infrared spectra with different signal-to-noise ratios](https://doi.org/10.1364/ao.57.005794), 2018, Applied Optics

> Removing the baseline from the spectra, which are measured by a
>   Fourier transform infrared spectrometer (FTIR), is an important
>   preprocessing step for further spectra analysis such as quantitative
>   and qualitative analysis. An automatic baseline correction method
>   named iterative averaging, which is based on the basic knowledge of
>   moving average, is presented. We also compared it to other methods,
>   such as rubber band, adaptive iterative reweight penalized least
>   squares, automatic iterative moving average, and morphological
>   weighted penalized least squares, using simulated and experimental
>   spectra with different signal-to-noise ratios (SNRs) to evaluate the
>   performance of these methods by performance metrics and to select an
>   appropriate method to analyze FTIR spectra. Performance metrics such
>   as root-mean-square error, goodness-of-fit coefficient, and chi-square
>   are calculated. The iterative averaging method achieves the best
>   results, which are judged by performance metrics values, when it is
>   applied to the FTIR spectra with different SNRs. It also can correct
>   the baseline of the FTIR spectra automatically, and improve the
>   capability and adaptability of the unsupervised online analysis of the
>   FTIR system effectively.

- Discussion on the R `hyperSpec` package [Fitting Baselines to Spectra](http://hyperspec.r-forge.r-project.org/blob/baseline.pdf), "section 3: Rubberband Method".

> spc.rubberband, a “rubberband” method that determines support points
>   by finding the convex hull of each spectrum. The baselines are then
>   piecewise linear or (smoothing) splines through the support points.

A closer contender could be found in Matlab with

- [%HYPERCONVEXHULLREMOVAL Performs spectral normalization via convex hull removal](https://github.com/isaacgerg/matlabHyperspectralToolbox/blob/master/hyperspectralToolbox/hyperConvexHullRemoval.m) from [MATLAB Hyperspectral Toolbox](https://github.com/isaacgerg/matlabHyperspectralToolbox)
- and a recent discussion in [How to implement concave rubberband correction for baseline removal in Matlab?](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/327344-how-to-implement-concave-rubberband-correction-for-baseline-removal-in-matlab)

Additionally, the topic of baseline/background/continuum/drift removal was recently active at SE.DSP (Signal Processing Stack Exchange):

- [How to perform a Rubberband-Correction on spectroscopic data?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/29290/15892)
- [Removing baseline drift from ECG signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/23511/15892)
- [Chromatography Baseline Placement](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/25078/15892)
- [Decomposition of a signal to slow and fast components](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/25348/15892)
- [Cancel Drift after numerical integration](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34348/15892)
- [Removing baseline drift from ECG signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/23511/15892)
- [Plotted ECG signals are not around Amplitude 0 line](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/47905/15892)